# how to make Mojolicious's url_for()->to_abs() return correct scheme (http or https) behind nginx

Tags: perl, nginx, reverse-proxy, mojolicious

Here is my situation:

1) Nginx listens both 80 and 443 port and forwards a request to Mojolicious app.

```
upstream ssltest {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name ssltest.server.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ssltest/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

2) In the Mojolicious app, I put this code:

```
get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;

  warn $c->url_for('/somepath')->to_abs;  # HERE

  $c->render(template => 'index');
};
```

I want that `url_for('/somepath')->to_abs` returns `https://ssltest.server.com/somepath` or `http://.../somepath`, depending on which protocol I use in my browser. **But it always returns `http`**

(There is some reason that I have to create an absolute path, rather than relative path)

So, I've tried to search in web.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mojolicious/zL-c4Tx1vCk/_ihsLRsNAgAJ

This link taught me I can pass the current protocol(http or https) to the Mojo app via a custom header `X-Forward-Proto`. However, url_for() still returned only `http`.

Then I tried such code:

```
warn $c->url_for('/somepath')->to_abs->scheme(
  $c->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-Proto')
);
```

It worked! But now I have to modify every occurrences of `url_for->to_abs` in the code.

Next, I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27834805/1150133
which uses a hook to modify `$c->req->url->base` itself. I tried to apply it:

```
# change 'scheme' of request url
hook 'before_dispatch' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->req->url->base->scheme( $c->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-Proto'));
};

get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;

  # url_for() seems to refer the request url to determine new url
  warn $c->url_for('/somepath')->to_abs;

  $c->render(template => 'index');
};
```

It worked very well.

**Now I want to know whether this is a correct way or not.** Is there any problem that would occur? Is there a better or the best way to acquire my goal?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, that's a good way, **but** I would make it more flexible.

First, there is never *a correct way* in Perl. Mojolicious is just Perl, too. [There is more than one way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it). Sometimes one or more ways are more correct than others. This is such a case.

Your code is fine and will get the job done. However, if you decide to deploy the application in a different way, and that header goes away, things go boom. So you should at least check for its existence.

```
# change 'scheme' of request url
hook 'before_dispatch' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->req->url->base->scheme( $c->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-Proto'))
    if $c->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-Proto');
};
```

Now if you run it locally with `morbo` and you don't have the header set, things should still work (assuming they broke in the first place, which sounds like a reasonable assumption I did not verify).

To see how to write unit tests for it, please refer to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46960660/1331451). It comes at the problem from a different side, but applies exactly.

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid that there may be the case that I should NOT modify the `req->url->base->scheme`. Now I can feel peace :)

Comment: @gypark you should in theory also be able to configure your nginx to do the conversion for you. That may be a smart thing to do, but I don't know how.

Comment: Doesn't Mojolicious have a `behind_proxy` setting like Dancer2 has for this exact purpose?

Comment: @PerlDuck it might. I didn't research.

Comment: @PerlDuck @simbabque oh, my... Thank you so much. I read the Dancer2 document, looked for the equivalent thing in Mojolicious, and found `MOJO_REVERSE_PROXY=1` did the same role. http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#PSGI-Plack I tried it in my code and it works very well without the hook. (That link also shows the use of hook just like in this post: http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Rewriting )

Comment: @gypark This is a funny coincidence :-). Just two days ago I had the same problem because I have set up an Apache proxy for client certificate authentication for my Dancer2 app. Dancer2 then always wanted to load `http://.../style.css` instead of `https://.../style.css` etc. because of the "wrong" `request.uri_base`. Luckily I found the [`behind_proxy`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Config.pod#behind_proxy_(boolean)) setting and am glad to hear that you found a similar setting for Mojolicious.