# Mojolicious url_for operation insecure in webservice

Tags: apache, perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am trying to return content with a web service. Behind an apache proxy if fails with "Operation insecure".

I read about adding an apache hook but it won't work for me. Setting the environment variable neither.
This is what I tried: [how to make Mojolicious's url_for()->to_abs() return correct scheme (http or https) behind nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009434/how-to-make-mojoliciouss-url-for-to-abs-return-correct-scheme-http-or-htt)

Maybe or webservice I have to do something else ? Also I use mojolicious lite.

Also the url_for is done in the template file .html.ep. I use it to call the web service from javascript.

I run Mojolicious 7.59 on Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way: the *apache proxy* must have some specific settings and also the *mojo* app must be in *reverse proxy* mode.

**Apache Settings**

Apache must know how to proxy the web services and it must tell mojo about the forwarding protocol.

- I put all my webservices under the */ws/* and I added it to *ProxyPass*
- My mojo app is at the same host at port 8080 so I proxy to *localhost:8080*.
- It is very important to set the *X-Forwarded-Proto*

At */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf* I changed this way:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8080/ws/ keepalive=On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

**Mojo Proxy**

The mojolicious app must know it is in reverse proxy. If you are using *hypnotoad* it may not be necessary. When I did some tests with *morbo* I had to run it this way:

```
MOJO_REVERSE_PROXY=1 morbo script.pl
```

There is more documentation at https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Reverse-proxy